# What is considered “production” of an illegal image?

Tags: united-states, internet, child-porn

Is a child sex abuse image considered “produced” by Bob if it was “received” or “viewed” on Bob’s computer? Does the computer displaying the image on Bob’s monitor count as him producing it? Or would Bob have to take the photo of the illegal image himself (or draw/render the photo if it’s considered an obscene image) to be judged as “producing” it?

Answer (score 3):

[18 USC 2251](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/18/2251) has various provisions that outlaw "producing" child porn, and in
[18 USC 2256(3)](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/18/2256) "producing" is defined as "producing, directing, manufacturing, issuing, publishing, or advertising". The same law also prohibits "transmitting a live visual depiction of such conduct", and also forbids one to "receive, exchange, buy, produce, display, distribute, or reproduce". [§2252](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/18/2252) has prohibitions against transportation, receiving and distribution of materials involving (previously prohibited) illegal production. In other words, "producing" does not include "viewing". §2252 itself also does not include "viewing" but it does include "accessing with intent to view", as does [§2252A](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/18/2252A). Bob can be prosecuted no matter what, the only question is exactly which words of what statute apply. As you can see if he is involved in content-creation or any form of distribution, that is "producing".

Comment: So in some alternate reality where the US prohibited *only* production, Bob would not be culpable under how the US defines production?

Comment: Yes, in that universe, Bob is not culpable.

Comment: I think I might’ve found a non-alternate reality situation. Suppose Bob viewed child abuse images in a foreign country on the internet. Given the wording of Section 2251(c) and 2260(a) of US Code Title 18, since he did not produce the images does this mean he is not culpable in the United States (obviously would be possibly culpable in the country he viewed from)? I found this from: https://www.justice.gov/criminal-ceos/citizens-guide-us-federal-law-extraterritorial-sexual-exploitation-children

Comment: The alternative reality requires repealing and rewriting existing laws to remove any reference to possession and receiving, and criminalizing only possession. But US law penalizes all of these things. You invocation of a foreign country is confusing. Are you asking whether a person can be prosecuted under US law for an act that in no way involves the US, other than Bob being a US citizen? E.g. can I be prosecuted under US law for consuming hashish in Amsterdam? Is that the question?

Comment: Well, I was trying to find a situation where mere reception couldn’t be prosecutable to illustrate that perhaps viewing does not necessarily constitute production. Under this statute, production of such images provided there is an intent to send them to the US is illegal, but it says nothing about merely receiving/possessing such images from outside the US. I suppose my question basically is: could Bob be convicted in the US if he viewed that content abroad? Because that would imply that viewing can be considered production (not counting the intent to import stuff).